# How to highlight table rows if error is found - Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#register-form").validate({
     rules: {
        fname: "required",
        surname: "required",
        middlename: "required",
       },
    messages: {
        fname: "Please enter your name",
        surname: "Please specify your surname",
        middlename: "Please specify your surname",

    },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
     }

    });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"  method="post"     id="register-form">
<table width="614" border="0">
<tr style="<?php echo $errorname_css; ?>">
<td width="153">First Name</td>
<td width="175">
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" /></td>
<td width="272">*<?php echo $fname_err; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="<?php echo $errorsurname_css; ?>">
 <td>Surname</td>   
<td><input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>" /></td>
<td>*<?php echo $surname_err; ?></td>
</tr>
 <tr  style="<?php echo $errormidname_css; ?>">
<td>Middle Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="middlename" value="<?php echo $middlename; ?>"  /></td>
<td>*<?php echo $middlename_err; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr  style="<?php echo $errormidname_css; ?>">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I would like to put the css inside the Jquery messages, but i dont know how, can someone help me with this? really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: put somethin in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hightlight/unhighlight methods

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
        fname: "required",
        surname: "required",
        middlename: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        fname: "Please enter your name",
        surname: "Please specify your surname",
        middlename: "Please specify your surname",

    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('tr').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('tr').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

then

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NDe3A/)